# What effect did William S. Burroughs's killing of his own wife have on his work?

Tags: william-s-burroughs

William S. Burroughs, postmodernist author of the "Beat Generation", killed his own wife in Mexico City after a wild party with Jack Kerouac and Alan Ginsberg.

How did this affect his subsequent work?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_S._Burroughs#cite_note-24) says "Although Burroughs was writing before the shooting of Joan Vollmer, this event marked him and, biographers argue, his work for the rest of his life", cited to Ted Morgan's biography *Literary Outlaw*. If someone can get hold of that book, there might be a good answer in there.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that prior to Joan's death, Burroughs wrote relatively little. As the scion of a rich family he was given a modest stipend, enough on which to live, so had no real need to work, or to sell stories or books. Encouraged by his literary friends Allen Ginsberg and Jack Kerouac he'd begun work on the semi-biographical novel *Junkie* prior to 1951 when he shot Joan but had not approached a publisher with it. It would not be published until 1953.

I went to the reference given in Wikipedia - the Burroughs biography *Literary Outlaw* - and found it had this to say on the subject of how Joan's death affected Burroughs and his writing:

> After Joan's death, Burroughs knew that the rest of his life would be a form of atonement for that one inexplicable moment, not only for the wife he had killed but for the havoc he had bought to those closest to him, his son and his parents, and he was haunted by these lines of Edwin Arlington Robinson's:

> There are mistakes too monstrous for remorse
> To tamper or dally with

It then goes on to explain that Burroughs seemed to genuinely believe that he was, at times, possessed by an evil spirit and that it was this spirit that had caused him to kill Joan. He claimed this wasn't an excuse, because he believed it was some personal failing that had led the entity to possess him. The biography continues:

> The irony of Joan's death was that it unlocked Burrough's literary vocation. Thanks to Joan, he was able to pursue a career as a writer. One form of atonement was a description of his demons, and one form of defense against them was the written word.

And this would seem to be the basis of the claim that Joan's death lead to an impact on his work. It wasn't so much that it changed his work, because he'd written relatively little beforehand. It's more that her death inspired him to write and that the shadow of that event found frequent expression in his fiction.

It is, perhaps, best to end by quoting Burroughs' own words on the subject, as the biography then goes on to do. They indicate that he himself believed the event had a huge impact on his writing. He wrote in the introduction of his second novel. *Queer*, written shortly after the shooting but not published until 1985:

> I am forced to the appalling conclusion that I would never have become a writer but for Joan's death, and to a realization of the extent to which this event has motivated and formulated my writing. I live with the constant threat of possession, and a constant need to escape from possession, from Control. So the death of Joan brought me in contact with the invader, the Ugly Spirit, and maneuvered me into a life long struggle, in which I have had no choice except to write my way out.